# Div does not show first line whenever new text loads in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I have div of id "TrancriptBox" in page. It contains text of number of lines.

When i scrolls it on iPad it works fine. But if i scrolls and change text of that div. It does not show first line of changed text. It shows scrolled position rather than new texts first line.

Code:

```
$("#TrancriptBox").text("");
$("#TrancriptBox").text(trancriptText);
```

"trancriptText" is text parameter passed to div.

Please suggest how to show first line of text whenever new text loads in div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call `scrollTop()`:

```
$("#TrancriptBox").text(trancriptText).scrollTop(0);
```

Given that you're explicitly resetting the `text()` of the element, you don't need to first unset the text (with `.text('')`), just apply the method directly with the new variable passed in.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("#TrancriptBox").empty().html(trancriptText);
```